# Efficiently computing sum of cross product for two 3D arrays in R

Tags: r, rcpp, cross-product, rcpparmadillo

For two 3D arrays in R, for example,

```
N <- 1000
x <- rnorm(N*3*3);   dim(x) <- c(N,3,3)
y <- rnorm(N*3*3);   dim(y) <- c(N,3,3)
```

I can do the following cross product by loop:

```
gg <- 0
for (n in 1:dim(x)[1]){
    gg <- gg + t(x[n,,]) %*% y[n,,]
}
```

My question is can we do it more efficiently (e.g., by vectorization or `rcpp`) for very large `N` instead of using loop?

Comment: there is matrix multiplication implemented in this post using Rcpp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191673/matrix-multiplication-in-rcpp

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I've written rcpp and tested against loop, but it is 2 times slower than loop... I think F. Privé's solution below is most fast according to my tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you rewrite your problem mathematically, you can show that it is equivalent to:

```
dim(x) <- c(3 * N, 3)
dim(y) <- c(3 * N, 3)
gg2 <- crossprod(x, y)
```

which should be very fast and should not make any copy.

Comment: Thank you very much! It runs about 12 times faster than loop on my computer!